# Slug generated having two hyphens at the end in rails 3.2 using friendly id?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, friendly-id

I am using [friendly_id 4.0.10.1](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/tree/4.0.10.1) gem for generating slug. I am using two columns to generate slug: **first_name** and **last_name**.

The **last_name** value can be empty. The problem arises in these cases:

```
   first_name  last_name  slug
1. Arun          Kumar    arun-kumar
2. Arun          Kumar    arun-kumar--2
3. Arun          Kumar    arun-kumar--3
```

I am expecting the slug to be like this: **arun-kumar-2**, **arun-kumar-3**.

I do not want those double hyphens to appear at the end. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this issue, and the linked docs:

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/170

> The "--" is used to separate the slug from the sequence. This allows
>   you to have a slug with a number in it.

You can configure `sequence_separator`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. What can I have as a sequence_separator so that the slug is user friendly?

Comment: I think configuring it to `''` Empty string will work.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh When I am keeping the separator empty I start getting duplicate index creation errors. The output is something like this: arun-kumar2, instead of arun-kumar-2.

Comment: What about '-' (Single hyphen) ?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, the string separator defaults to '-'.